# How to make svg not selectable in xsl?

Tags: svg, xsl-fo

I am trying to create watermark in pdf using xslt. 
I have created watermark, but the problem is that text on page is not selectable only watermark is.

How to make text selectable, and watermark to be shown in background.

How to achive it using svg. I cannot use image, because it shold be a lot of different text, so it would be hard to create so many images. Is there any way to do it.

Is there any attribute or element to make it not selectable?

```
<fo:instream-foreign-object z-index="-1">
            <svg:svg>
              <svg:g font-size="50px" >
                <svg:text fill="#FF0000"
                          >
                  watermark
                </svg:text>
              </svg:g>
            </svg:svg>
          </fo:instream-foreign-object>
```

Comment: adding pointer-events="none" as an attribute to the text element should do it, assuming it's supported.

Comment: You need additional information in your question. How are you creating pdf? What code or are you printing from browser?

Comment: I don't think this is an XSLT question. Until you know what you want to produce, you can't start to think about what code you need to write to produce it.

Comment: I am using some xsl-fo compiler like AnttenaHouse or Ibex to create pdf, from xsl file.

Comment: Show more of the fo, specifically where you are inserting the watermark and is it above or below the text.

Comment: AH Formatter from Antenna House supports setting two sets of watermark text (see around http://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf60/docs/ahf-optset.html#watermark-text).  AFAICT, Ibex doesn't have a documented method for adding watermarks.  If you are using just AH Formatter, you would use a different solution compared to using Ibex, so it would help to know for sure which formatter you are using.